# How to prevent unwanted clicks if someone clicks too fast?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a sidebar with moveable panels - you can see in the snippet they move left or right when you click `Menu item` or `Go back`.

The problem is that if you click fast on the buttons (You can recreate the issue by clicking fast and many times on the buttons), it will sometimes calculate `currentIndex++` (or `--`) twice on the same panel which will make it stuck, and then it will just keep adding `translate` amount to the same panel.

In my example there are only 3 panels with width `40`, so it should only move somewhere between `translate-x-0` to `-translate-x-120`, but if it gets stuck, it will simply keep adding jumps of 40 to the stuck panels, so you can see something like `-translate-x-800` if you just keep clicking

```js
const App = {
    data() {
        return {
                sidebarWidth: 40,
                currentIndex: 0,      
       }
    },
    computed: {
            position() {
                if (this.currentIndex === 0) {
            return 'translate-x-0'
        } else {
                  return `-translate-x-${this.sidebarWidth * this.currentIndex}`
        }
            }
        }
}

Vue.createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div class="h-screen flex">
        <div class="flex container w-40 h-80 bg-black mx-auto my-auto text-black overflow-hidden">
            <div class="sidebar container flex transform duration-1000" :class="position">

                <div class="sidebar-menu flex-shrink-0 w-40 transform duration-1000 bg-gray-300">
                    <button @click="currentIndex++">Menu item</button>
                </div>

                <div class="sidebar-menu flex-shrink-0 w-40 bg-blue-300 transform duration-1000">
                    <div class="flex flex-col">
                        <button class="flex justify-start" @click="currentIndex--">
                        Go back
                        </button>

                        <button class="flex justify-start" @click="currentIndex++">
                        Menu item
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="sidebar-menu flex-shrink-0 w-40 transform duration-1000 bg-red-300">
                    <div class="flex flex-col">
                        <button class="flex justify-start" @click="currentIndex--">
                        Go back
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can try debounce function. See this link https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the index increment/decrement is not limited/truncated, so it's possible to exceed the actual number of menus even if using a debouncer.

Determine the menu count by querying `.sidebar-menu` elements in the component, and prevent the index from exceeding this maximum value:

```js
export default {
    mounted() {
        this.menuCount = this.$el.querySelectorAll('.sidebar-menu').length
    },
    methods: {
        nextIndex(delta) {
           this.currentIndex = (this.currentIndex + delta) % this.menuCount
        }
    }
}
```

Then bind that method to the `click`-handlers:

```html
<button class="flex justify-start" @click="nextIndex(-1)">
  Go back
</button>
<button class="flex justify-start" @click="nextIndex(1)">
  Menu item
</button>
```

```js
const App = {
    data() {
        return {
                sidebarWidth: 40,
                currentIndex: 0,
                menuCount: 0,
       }
    },
    computed: {
       position() {
           if (this.currentIndex === 0) {
               return 'translate-x-0'
           } else {
              return `-translate-x-${this.sidebarWidth * this.currentIndex}`
           }
       }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.menuCount = this.$el.querySelectorAll('.sidebar-menu').length
    },
    methods: {
        nextIndex(delta) {
           this.currentIndex = (this.currentIndex + delta) % this.menuCount
        }
    }
}

Vue.createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div class="h-screen flex">
        <div class="flex container w-40 h-80 bg-black mx-auto my-auto text-black overflow-hidden">
            <div class="sidebar container flex transform duration-1000" :class="position">

                <div class="sidebar-menu flex-shrink-0 w-40 transform duration-1000 bg-gray-300">
                    <button @click="nextIndex(1)">Menu item</button>
                </div>

                <div class="sidebar-menu flex-shrink-0 w-40 bg-blue-300 transform duration-1000">
                    <div class="flex flex-col">
                        <button class="flex justify-start" @click="nextIndex(-1)">
                        Go back
                        </button>

                        <button class="flex justify-start" @click="nextIndex(1)">
                        Menu item
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="sidebar-menu flex-shrink-0 w-40 transform duration-1000 bg-red-300">
                    <div class="flex flex-col">
                        <button class="flex justify-start" @click="nextIndex(-1)">
                        Go back
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are awesome! My original code was very similar when I was using Alpine.js, I just couldn't get it to work with Vue! You did it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using debounce from lodash. It works by aggregating repeated events and only firing the last one. You can run the example to see how it works.

```js
const App = {
    data() {
        return {
                sidebarWidth: 40,
                currentIndex: 0,      
       }
    },
    methods: {
      debounceInput: _.debounce(function (e) {
        // decides whether to increment or decrement current Index
        if (e == "+"){
          this.currentIndex++
        }
        else if (e == '-') {
          this.currentIndex--
        }
      }, 300)
    }
    ,
    computed: {
            position() {
                if (this.currentIndex === 0) {
            return 'translate-x-0'
        } else {
                  return `-translate-x-${this.sidebarWidth * this.currentIndex}`
        }
            }
        }
}

Vue.createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="h-screen flex">
    <div class="flex container w-40 h-80 bg-black mx-auto my-auto text-black overflow-hidden">
      <div class="sidebar container flex transform duration-1000" :class="position">

        <div class="sidebar-menu flex-shrink-0 w-40 transform duration-1000 bg-gray-300">
          <button @click="debounceInput('+')">Menu item</button>
        </div>

        <div class="sidebar-menu flex-shrink-0 w-40 bg-blue-300 transform duration-1000">
          <div class="flex flex-col">
            <button class="flex justify-start" @click="debounceInput('-')">
                        Go back
                        </button>

            <button class="flex justify-start" @click="debounceInput('+')">
                        Menu item
                        </button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="sidebar-menu flex-shrink-0 w-40 transform duration-1000 bg-red-300">
          <div class="flex flex-col">
            <button class="flex justify-start" @click="currentIndex--">
                        Go back
                        </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```